# Xpath select all tr after second tr

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I using HtmlAgilityPack i have a html of table

```
<TABLE class=default cellSpacing=0 width="95%" border=0 name="LISTA_MOV"><TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=normal colSpan=5 align=center>ACCOUNT IN&nbsp;EUR: ES1030580147982720000036 - HAZERA ESPAÑA</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=columnas vAlign=top width=80 align=center>Date</TD>
<TD class=columnas vAlign=top width=60 align=center>Value date</TD>
<TD class=columnas vAlign=top align=center>Reference</TD>
<TD class=columnas vAlign=top align=center>Amount</TD>
<TD class=columnas vAlign=top align=center>Balance</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=columnas vAlign=top width=80 align=center><INPUT onclick="sortTable('LISTA_MOV',0,true,'Date');" alt="Ordenar Ascendente" src="/BE/util_apoyo/img/esp/orden_1.gif" type=image border=0 name=Sort>&nbsp;<INPUT onclick="sortTable('LISTA_MOV',0,false,'Date');" alt="Ordenar Descendente" src="/BE/util_apoyo/img/esp/orden_2.gif" type=image border=0 name=Sort_Date_down0></TD>...
```

when i trying to date,(that in the td with date value) with Xpath `"//tr//td[1]"`

```
 GeneralUtils.GetListDataFromHtmlSourse(PageData, "//tr//td[1]");
```

i getting 40 values and the two fist one i don't need they are " nbsp;" and "Date",
sow i just need to fix my Xpath that will retur me all tr after second(or more in other case)

How can i need to change Xpath  `//tr//td[1]` that it will look for tr after second tr elements.

Comment: Why don't you just use the [LINQ .Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) method to step over the first two?

Comment: I can check if my list contains at[1] =nbsp or date ,but i want to do this with Xpath i think it more appropriate way.

Comment: Why? It's essentially the same thing and your intent is much more clear IMO. Anyway, you can use [position()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675199.aspx). Something like `"Elem[position() > 2]"`

Comment: @DGibbs This actually makes sense to use XPath, because an intelligent XPath processor will never even touch the first two entries, whereas if you use `skip()` you might have to serialize stuff (this is of course much more relevant if this is a large element). Also, imho the XPath way is much clearer (but I am an XPath/XQuery developer, so this might depend on the individual background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like DGibbs said you can use position, apply it like:

```
GeneralUtils.GetListDataFromHtmlSourse(PageData, "//tr[position() > 2]//td[1]");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using XPath `position()` filter, for example :

```
//tr[position() > 2]//td[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not be more specific in your XPath? Something like:

```
/TABLE[@name='LISTA_MOV']/tr[position() > 1]/td[1]
```